SQLAlchemy преобразовать объект в данные
Я использую SQLite и SQLAlchemi для некоторого анализа.
Файл db.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///Report_db.db'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db.query_property()

Модель данных:
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Numeric
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from db import Base

class Manager(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    AM = Column(String, index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    Report = Column(String)

    STL_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(STL.id), index=True)
    TeamLead_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(TeamLead.id), index=True)

    STL_Table = relationship('STL')
    TeamLead_Table = relationship('TeamLead')

При попытке получить данные из БД, я получаю их в виде списка [<models.Manager object at 0x000001B1C7C41700>, <models.Manager object at 0x000001B1C7C416D0>, <models.Manager object at 0x000001B1C7C411C0>]
query = Manager.query.all()
print(query)

как можно преобразовать их в нормальные колонки и строки для дальнейшей работы в Polars или Pandas DataFrame?
при попытке пройти по строкам циклом, выдается ошибка TypeError: 'Manager' object is not iterable

Что-то тут не так. Не дёргайте куски кода, приведите нормально код, где у вас ошибка. И полный трейс ошибки. Где код с циклом? query у вас это список, значит по нему можно пройти циклом. А вот уже объекты в переменной цикла будут типа Manager вы можете брать из них нужные поля по типу manager.id, manager.email. Зачем вам список колонок, вы не знаете, какие у вас будут колонки? Если нужно, их можно достать списком, но обычно так не делается.

Я не стала его вставлять, так как он выдает ошибку итерации. for row in query:       dict_row = dict(row)

То есть вы привели ошибку, но не привели код, который её вызывает? Не делайте так в будущем. Если есть ошибка, то должен быть и код к этой ошибке. В общем, не нужно вам то, что вы делаете, берите конкретные поля, которые вам нужны: for row in query: print(row.email). Если вы нормально маппинг сделали, всё будет работать.
